# How to copy the contents of an unpacked struct to a __packed__ struct?

Tags: c, struct

I read about `__packed__` from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) and, I understood that when `__packed__` is used in a `struct` or `union`, it means that the member variables are placed in such a way to minimize the memory required to store the `struct` or `union`.

Now, consider the structures in the following code. They contain same elements (same `type`, same variable names and placed in the same order). The difference is, one is `__packed__` and the other is not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    typedef struct unpacked_struct {
        char c;
        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
    }ups;

    typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) packed_struct {
        char c;
        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
    }ps;

    printf("sizeof(my_unpacked_struct)  : %d \n", sizeof(ups));
    printf("sizeof(my_packed_struct)    : %d \n", sizeof(ps));

    ups ups1 = init_ups();
    ps ps1;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way where we can copy unpacked structure `ups1` into packed structure `ps1` without doing a `member-variable-wise-copy`? Is there something like `memcpy()` that is applicable here?

Comment: I dont understand why would you need something like this. I believe you will use either packed or regular structure, not both ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you've just gotta write it out. Nothing in standard C (or any standard I know of) will do this for you. Write it once and never think about it again.

```
ps ups_to_ps(ups ups) {
    return (ps) {
        .c = ups.c,
        .i = ups.i,
        .f = ups.f,
        .d = ups.d,
    };
}
```

Comment: Yep.  `x.c = y.c;  x.i = y.i; ...`

Comment: @MattJoiner I was afraid so. I'm going to wait for some more (different) answers! .. Thanks for the good answer.. +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

Without detailed knowlegde of the differences of the memory layout of the two structures: No.

Comment: Good point. But once we start programming based on the memory layout then we may run into some unnecessary/unwanted complications! .. Thanks for your answer. +1 from me! :)